# Error computing the expiration data for item

Tags: error, timer-jobs, information-management, expiration

[image]EventID 7972 Task Category: Information Policy Management Source:
Document Management Server

```
> 
> Error computing the expiration date for item
> http:///webapp/sites/sitecoll/documentlib/document.rtf
> 
> Error:  The file documentlib/document.rtf has been modified by
> SHAREPOINT\system on 08 Mar 2012 13:51:11 -0600.
```

It spammed at 1:51pm 5 times, and 3:00pm 5 times. I'm not sure why it happens. My information policy and expiration policy runs at 2am and 3am repectively. It happened this morning also at 7am 8 times, and last night at 9pm, and so on.

### **UPDATE:**


These are the logs associated with the error:

> 0x81020015The file
>   List/file.rtf has
>   been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 01 Feb 2013 08:36:37 -0600.
>
> Possible mismatch between the reported error with code = 0x81070901
>   and message: "The file List/file.rtf has been modified
>   by SHAREPOINT\system on 01 Feb 2013 08:36:37 -0600." and the returned
>   error with code 0x81020037.
>
> Error computing the expiration date for item
>   `http://sharepoint/sites/subsite/subsite/List/file.rtf`.  Error:  The file
>   List/file.rtf has
>   been modified by SHAREPOINT\system on 01 Feb 2013 08:36:37 -0600.
>
> Leaving Monitored Scope (UpdateExpireDate.OnEvent). Execution
>   Time=63.1552334165376
>
> Leaving Monitored Scope (Event Receiver (Microsoft.Office.Policy,
>   Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c,
>   Microsoft.Office.RecordsManagement.Internal.UpdateExpireDate)).
>   Execution Time=64.022382733001

Comment: Couple ideas: Do you have anything else that could be running at the same time and changing the document?  Is it possible a workflow ran on the document at those two times?  I believe the expiration policy calculator is run whenever a document is updated.  Also, are you editing the document within the Date Calculator besides just returning a date?

Comment: There are no workflows on any of these document libraries.

Comment: Ironically, some if not most of them are when they get posted. So if the document is posted at 3:15, there is an error in the event viewer of the above that matches it.

Comment: Is the DateCalculator function changing the document?  Is it possible that the user is editing the document in office or another application immediately after posting it?

Comment: We have a workflow that runs when a document is updated, and we occasionally see an error like this when a user checks out the document shortly after uploading it. (we should have broken into an event handler so that part of it could be synchronous.)  I don't know if this could happen with a date calculator or not, but it definitely could if you are directly changing the document in the date-calculator, which would not be recommended.

Comment: What is that date calculator job called? Is it a job definition?

Comment: The timer job is called Information Management Policy. I am not sure though that the whole timer job runs when the items are updated.  It may just run the datecalculator function on that item.

Comment: thanks. this helps me a bit, but i'm still inthe dark on why its happening...

Comment: Are the times that you are seeing the errors consistent with the times that the Information Management Policy and Expiration Policy jobs are running? It looks like it from your post but please confirm. Thanks

Comment: No. The Expiration and Info Management Policy is runnning on a weekly basis. This runs on a daily almost bihourly basis.

Comment: @Mike, I know it has taken time, but I my mind clicks, it is a permission issue on a list. ie. ListItem Update done where only add rights has been given. You should be able to link up the error time in the services with the ULS to look for the request.

Comment: No, all users have contributor access or greater. I've tried to reactivate the retention policy feature, I've tried to recreate the policy, etc.. nothing works and those errors keep chucking...

Comment: The ULS logs just say error computing expiration date with no other surrounding supporting logs...

Comment: I am getting same error in event log. Did u get to know the cause of this error?

Comment: no, not yet. I am all out of ideas here.

Comment: I would look at concurrent processes trying to change the metadata on the doc at the same time. We know the expiration is being added, but I bet your workflow is also trying at the same moment to add metadata to the file from the SPlist columns. 

I think Those fields are stored in the file and in the SPlist. I think it is likely the file edit that is failing due to a lock on the file. 

One way to check would be to count the number of office documents in the list and compare it to the number of spams you get. It might just be Word Docs, or All office docs etc.

Comment: Ok, so this has been tried already (Nov 8 2012): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/c6e51231-f68c-438a-ac78-3a2365f34558

Has this been tried? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-BZ/sharepointgeneralprevious/thread/9fa4a7ca-eb05-49a8-a4f5-669ee2b769ce

Comment: I've found both fo those forum threads before and commented on the second one. Both in my case are not a factor. All users have contribute ability and Information Rights Management is disabled in CA

Comment: Mike can you check if the server date and time is correct across the farm?

Comment: It is the same time zone: Central

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It **MAY** have something to do with having the same subject/filename, so SharePoint has to rename the file/post after it has uploaded, as well as (at the same time), execute the expiration date of the content. Maybe two different sessions doing two different things can cause this error...

1. Renaming the file (Session 1)
2. Calculating and updating the expiration date/time (Session 2)

These session may be fighting for the right to edit the post. I'm taking a stab in the dark that this may be it since for each library that has an error, it does have an expiration policy and they both have the SharePoint name change present, for example:

A) Post A posted at 10:00am named "Testing"

B) Post B posted at 10:05am named "Testing" then gets renamed to "Testing **1758**"

Answer (score 3):

There is one generic error in SharePoint that will throw

> the file xxxx has been modified by SHAREPOINT\system

And that is when you don't have `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;` But that error is old, really old IIRC.

But the likely reason is that you **may be performing more than one update in the same request, so the second update will throw that error** because it will think there is another user updating.

Comment: but that many times? I don't have any custom code for these lists, so I'm not performing the `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true`

Comment: That was just for reference, what I mean is that somehow your job is running twice or more, custom code or not.

Comment: Mike do you have any way of checking to see if there are 2 updates happening at the same time? Do you have access to sql logs or monitor?

Comment: I updated my question to include the logs on the time of the incident

Comment: Whether you agree with F.Aquino or not it is very likely that you have one of a couple problems that present the same: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7094424/errorcode-2130575305-0x81020037-in-spitemeventreceiver-with-listitem-update
1. You are updating a cached item when the original has been changed
2. You are updating a read only field
3. You have a race condition and something quicker is updating simultaneously

Perhaps a short delay and then retrieve a fresh object before trying to update it will be sufficient.

Comment: The library where these events happen are email enabled, and it is emailed to the library, not posted manually.